# How to find Fourier Transform Coefficients from a .wav file?

Tags: python, fft, librosa, fourier-descriptors

Well, I have done a good amount of research on Speech data, I was able to return discrete Fourier transform of real or complex sequence from a wav file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import numpy as np
rate, data = wav.read('Data/File1.wav')
fft_out = fft(data)
%matplotlib inline
plt.plot(data, np.abs(fft_out))
plt.show()
```

When I tried to save this np.abs(fft_out) data, it is ultimately a 1D array data, which is quite obvious

But I need some help in extracting features (fourier coefficients) from the fourier transformed data, can somebody show some light?

Ultimately, I am being asked to create a final dataset with important features from fourier transformed signals

**Note: I don't need the exact code for this, but any direction would be helpful.
My main task is go get important features extracted from a fourier transformed data.**

Comment: What do you mean by "Fourier coefficients"?  When you do a Fourier transform on a 1D sequence of samples, you get back a 1D sequence with the intensity at each frequency bin.  The first entry is the DC coefficient.  The size of each bin in Hz depends on the data rate and the size of your input.  If you provide 8000 samples at 8 kHz, each bin is 1Hz wide.

Answer (score 0):

outputs of fft function are fourier coefficients. for each frequency there is one coefficient in 1D array.

[Fourier equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHTKa.png)

as in this equation cn is coefficient . for x=0 the coefficient is fft_out[0]